# Google Drive API Files.list Query returns empty with some combinations

Tags: google-drive-api

> EDIT: works now in same conditions

It appears I can't form a query that lists files in a specific folder, not trashed, of more than one mime type. This very specific (but common) query returns an empty list.

If I drop any one of the conditions, it works.

These work:

```
"root" in parents and trashed=false and mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
```

,

```
"root" in parents and trashed=**true** and (mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
or mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.document")
```

,

```
"root" in parents and (mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
or mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.document")
```

,

```
trashed=false and (mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
or mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.document")
```

But this returns empty:

```
"root" in parents and trashed=false and (mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
or mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.document")
```

--

parent doesn't have to be "root", fails with any folder ID, also other mime types, mimeType contains, etc.

Comment: Plese edit your question, It's hard to read.

Comment: double check that nextPageToken in the response is null. It is theoretically possible that your results are on a subsequent page.

Comment: I did, don't know know what wasn't working, now exactly the same thing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're query:

```
"root" in parents and trashed=false and (mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.folder" or mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.document")
```

works because it returns some of my Drive files when I run it. It maybe that you did not indicate the "`fields`" parameters that's why you're saying it's empty.

Execute it [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list?q=%2522root%2522+in+parents+and+trashed%253Dfalse+and+(mimeType%253D%2522application%252Fvnd.google-apps.folder%2522+or+mimeType%253D%2522application%252Fvnd.google-apps.document%2522)&fields=files%252CincompleteSearch%252Ckind%252CnextPageToken&_h=2&) and see for yourself. I've already ticked "all fields" to make sure it returns the corresponding matches.

Comment: thanks, i don't understand what wasn't working, i did indicate fields.